# Excel: Create dynamic table from named range in another sheet

Tags: excel, apache-poi

I'm creating templates reports to be filled by Apache-Poi.

I made some graph reports using named ranges, without problems. So, I don't need to know the amount of rows to graph it.

I have my presentation sheet separately from my data sheet (so I can hide the data sheet).

**How can I have a table in the presentation sheet created from the data of the data sheet?**

For instance, with my application I fill the table in the data sheet having 3 rows, I want to have a formatted table in the presentation sheet (with filters) populated with those 3 rows in the data sheet. And then if I fill the data sheet with 9 rows, well, you get the point. Any idea?

**Edited**: I'm working in an Export to Excel functionality for an application. What I do is to use an excel file as a report template, then with Apache POI, I clone the file, populate it with the report data, and then serve this file to be downloaded by the client browser.

I only fill the data in the Data sheet with Apache POI. Now, on the other reports, with my graphs on the presentation sheet, I don't have to do anything more than complete the data table (because I'm using named ranges).

I'm adding some screenshots with dummy data in order to explain a little more.

-- *Data Sheet* --

[image: Data sheet]

-- *Presentation Sheet* -- (what I want to achieve)

[image: Presentation sheet]

Comment: What you want to show in the table could please explain it bit more. If you have any snap please upload it.